# What Jedis Connection Factory should be used for AWS Redis (cluster mode disabled)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using Spring Jedis for my application. I am interacting with a Amazon Redis (cluster mode disabled). My question is

1. What JedisConnectionFactory should I use?
2. In my code I want to write to master and read from all read
   replicas. How can I achieve it?